# How to differentiate the performance of Named Entity Recognition from standard dictionaries

Tags: python, file, dictionary, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Problem:  What is the use of Named Entity Recognition when we can do the same with dictionaries.

I'm trying to solve a document classification problem, where NER helps to tag the document but realized what is the use of NER when we can map the same based on dictionary.

Library : SpaCy

How NER works really, how it differs from normal dictionaries?  Any Suggestions.

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jan  Thanks, I tried to explain. Please let me know, how I can improve.